# PHP how can i use ServerPush HTTP2 on IIS10

Tags: php, http2, server-push, iis-10

I have a little question like a title.

How can i use ServerPush HTTP2 with PHP on IIS10?

Many thank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[IIS only supports Push through the ASP.NET or similar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-10/http2-on-iis#what-about-push). Also it does not support through HTTP Link Headers like many servers and CDNs do.

So HTTP/2 Push cannot be used in IIS via PHP at the moment as far as I am aware.