# HTTP/2 Server push with PHP on IIS Server

Tags: php, windows, iis, push, http2

I want to test a server push over PHP. I have the following configuration:

- PHP 7.4
- IIS 10.0
- Opera Browser 65
- Windows 10

It's a very small file to see if the server push works. It's just a test.

```html
<?php header("Link: </test.css>; rel=preload; as=style"); ?>

<html>

    <head>
        <title>Test Server Push</title>
        <link href="/test.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>

    <h1>Test Server Push</h1>

    <p>Hello Push!</p>

    </body>

</html>
```

The developer tools of Opera show me as protocol h2 (for http/2). The initiator says "other" in the file test.css. At the waterfall text.css also says "Waiting (TTFB)". I mean, that shouldn't be there then.

It uses https and a valid certificate is stored (green lock).
I think all requirements for the server push with HTTP/2 are fulfilled.

Google Chrome shows it the same way.

What could be the mistake here? Or does a server push have to be activated somewhere under IIS? This is normally enabled by default in HTTP/2, isn't it?

Thanks for your help.

Added:
Screenshot from developer tools:

With the header command (php):
[image]

Without header command (php):
[image]

The only difference is with the initiator. Here I expect "push / other".

Comment: could you share your browser network monitor screenshot? and did you compare both the response time with push and without push?

Comment: I added the two screenshots.

Answer (score 2):

IIS only supports Push through the ASP.NET or similar. Also it does not support through HTTP Link Headers like many servers and CDNs do.
So HTTP/2 Push cannot be used in IIS via PHP at the moment as far as I am aware.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-10/http2-on-iis#what-about-push

https://blog.cloudflare.com/using-http-2-server-push-with-php/

Comment: I also found these two sources. However, I didn't find out that it doesn't work with IIS.

But okay. As long as I didn't misunderstand the code and it's only the technical support...

Comment: you could refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50287462/php-how-can-i-use-serverpush-http2-on-iis10